# Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: MatDivider

Tags: angular

Getting following error: 
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
More than one component matched on this element.
Make sure that only one component's selector can match a given element.
Conflicting components:

```
MatDivider,MatDivider ("   {{headerData}}
                                </div>
                                [ERROR ->]<mat-divider></mat-divider>
```

Using following import for this

```
import {MatDividerModule} from '@angular/material/divider';
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. As soon as I imported it from the main material library instead, I stopped receiving the error and was able to run the app.

`import {MatDividerModule} from '@angular/material';`